# CSS - Can't have a div to auto-fit with the screen height

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

In the below I have 2 div containers.

**Container 1** which contains a google map div that looks like the below :

**HTML**

```
  <div class="container">

  <div class="mapCanvas2" #mapCanvas2></div>

  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
height: 64%;
width: 100%;
}

.mapCanvas2{
position:relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

**Container 2**

```
.container2{
 height: 36%;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

**The problem:**

On some **screens** (depending on its height) a blank space shows up below **container 2** to hide it I must set the height value of `.container` to 67% or above which is of course not a solution.

Comment: Have you tried using `VH` instead of `%`?

Comment: where have you placed the container2 ?

Comment: @Deckerz treied Vh already, it has the same effect

Comment: @karthik below `container1`

Comment: apply body height `100vh`. that will resolve your pblm. https://jsfiddle.net/p76v1qrw/

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai was already 100% and changed it to 100vh, but it didn't change anything

Comment: did you check the fiddle i have shared?

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai of course

Comment: i have not seen any issue in my fiddle. could you reproduce your issue in fiddle. so that we can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flex, by specifing `flex:1` you make the second container fill the remaining space :

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 30%;
  background: red;
}

.container-2 {
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="mapCanvas2" #mapCanvas2> map </div>

</div>
<div class="container-2"></div>
```